# Are there any rules/theories on using certain melody/instrument/voice to arouse certain feeling?

Tags: music, anime-production

When I hear **the [ed 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ulw8aQc1pHs) of *Inuyasha the Final Act*** or **the [ed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=arOmXIT3HBA) of *Detective Conan Movie 07: Crossroad in the Ancient Capital***, it always makes me picture a scene of a spot almost fully covered by fallen and falling cherry blossoms. (Especially [1:08~1:20](https://youtu.be/arOmXIT3HBA?t=68) in the ed of *Conan*.)

I checked out the original MVs in the anime, and the scenes in the eds do contain cherry blossoms. Besides, stories in both anime have something to do with cherry blossom, too. Therefore, it's quite safe to say that the producers meant to use the music to create an atmosphere of cherry blossom.

I'm not sure whether that's only my personal feeling or a common feeling. However, neither did I know the origin of the music nor watched the MV the first time I listened to these two pieces of music, so it's probably common among quite a few audiences to picture a cherry blossom scene. I think that there might be some rules or theories (used by anime producers) on how certain melody/instrument/voice arouses certain feeling.

Comment: Not specific for these particular scenes (because what kind of music I expected was actually different than the premise of this question), but for "*there might be some rules or theories (used by anime producers) on how certain melody/instrument/voice arouses certain feelings*", [music psychology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Music_psychology) might be broadly relevant.

Comment: @AkiTanaka Dudes, your links... The video in Inuyasha link is blocked in the US due to copyright, the volume of the Conan video is too low.

Comment: @AkiTanaka Besides, cherry blossoms appear very early in the original Conan MV, so using the original MV would make it hard to tell whether the sakura scene in audiences' mind is aroused by the music or by the imagery. I think you need to give the viewers a chance to experience the feeling aroused by merely the music without the imagery.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know if the Inuyasha link is blocked in the US. I've rolled it back.